# IE8 input type image is showing border even, when I set border to none

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, input

I have used input type image to display my custom style buttons, but for some reason IE8 shows border even when I set in CSS border to none. In other browsers it is not showing border at all.

```
input[type=image] {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't support that selector very consistently in my experience; give the input a class and then style it with that instead.

```
<input type="image" class="imageinput" name="whatever" />

input.imageinput {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: IE8 which the OP is refering to, does support attribute selectors: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t13

Comment: Hi, thanx for answer, but it didn't help.

Comment: you can just use a normal button, but give it a background image via css selector...

Comment: @naivists When I say 'IE', I meant older versions too - it's been my experience that it's just easier to use a class for consistency across older browsers.

Comment: @newbie There is no reason why it shouldn't work. Can you post your button HTML and your new css?

Comment: There is nothing special around this element, I just don't understand why it doesnt work...

Answer (score 5):

Use the `outline` CSS property:

```
input[type="image"] {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

`outline` draws a line around the element's margin, without contributing to the element width, and in this case IE8 might have a default outline specified. Read more about it [at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp).

Answer (score 1):

first of all thanks for asking this question. I've faced this prob a year ago, you can choose the way you need but what I've done is simply imported this CSS as the starting point in my style.css and because of which it doesn't provides me an undesirable output

```
/* Reset CSS */

body, html {
    height:100%;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    line-height:1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style:none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:none;
}
:focus {
    outline:0;
}
del {
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* Floating & Alignment  */

.fl {
    float:left;
}
.fr {
    float:right;
}
.ac {
    text-align:center;
}
.ar {
    text-align:right;
}

/* Clear Floats  */

.col-full:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.fix {
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:-1px 0 0;
}
html body * span.clear, html body * div.clear, html body * li.clear, html body * dd.clear {
    background:none;
    border:0;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    font-size:0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

If you'll keep an habit of importing this css it will never provide you an undesirable output in any browser.

Thanks!